# what is valid complete object mean?

Tags: c++

i get confused in this part 
while we are using dynamic_cast to get ensure that the conversion result between pointers is valid complete object of the destination type , i can't get what is meaning by valid complete object 
here is example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class Base { virtual void dummy() {}


 };
class Derived: public Base {public:
void print(){cout << "NiGHt!\n";
 int a; };

int main () {
try {
Base * pba = new Derived;
Base * pbb = new Base;
Derived * pd;

pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pba);
if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on first type-cast.\n";

pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pbb);
if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on second type-cast.\n";

 } catch (exception& e) {cout << "Exception: " << e.what();}

 return 0;
}
```

if this two lines indicate that the conversion result succeed so why i can't use pointer pba to get into Derived class ?

```
pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pba);
if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on first type-cast.\n";
```

Comment: The second cast would not succeed in real code.

Comment: [dynamic_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting) Informally, you could say an object of a complete type, is an object instantiation belonging to a fully defined class. A class may make use of an object with an incomplete type as a member, like [this](http://pastebin.com/nEA9wiDp)

Comment: Fix your indentation

Answer (score 0):

The line `pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pba);` means that cast the `pba` pointer (which is a pointer to a `Base` class, however it contains a `Derived` object because: `Base * pba = new Derived`) to a pointer pointing to a `Derived` object. This cast will fail if there is no relationship between `Base` and `Derived` (ie: `Derived` must be derived from `Base`) and will return 0.

And why cannot you use `pba` to get the `Derived` class? Becuase `pba` is a pointer to a `Base` class. So it has no idea that there even is a `Derived` class.

Reference: [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)